# is there any command prompt code for windows 10 to obtain the last factory reset date and or time

Tags: cmd, windows-10, reset

I just want to know the last factory reset date of windows 10 by using command prompt.

I went through many sites and answers by different persons but they really don't work. I tried this on command prompt but not sure about the results :

```
systeminfo | find /i "Boot Time"
```

The command shows the last rebooted date and time through command prompt.

I need to display the exact date of factory reset with some specified format like day/month/year.

Answer (score 2):

Every reset or feature update id listed here

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Source OS (Updated on 3/26/2019 13:24:12)
```

The last one is shown by this command

```
systeminfo
```

and read the *Original Install Date*.

There are a million question and answers on stackoverflow about using a `for` loop to parse date outputs.

You question is about system administration and not about programming so is best on https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com. When you acquire the information and move to programming a solution then you ask here.